# Ef Core decimal presicion warning despite having a precision set

Tags: entity-framework-core

In our project we get the following warning:

```
The decimal property '"UnitPriceIncl"' is part of a key on entity type '"Position"'. If the configured precision and scale don't match the column type in the database, this will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Consider using a different property as the key, or make sure that the database column type matches the model configuration and enable decimal rounding warnings using 'SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON'.
```

But we do set the precision on the `UnitPriceIncl` property:

```
        position.Property(aip => aip.UnitPriceIncl).HasPrecision(precision: 14, scale: 4).IsRequired();
```

This is also the precision that is defined on the database table.
Is the problem, that the field is used in combination in a primary key together with `InvoiceId` and  `ProductId` which both are int's?

```
        invoicePosition.HasKey("invoiceId", nameof(Invoice.Position.ProductId), nameof(Invoice.Position.UnitPriceIncl));
```

Or are we missing a configuration?

Ef Core Version: 6.0.8

Comment: Why are you using a `decimal` in a primary key in the first place? This isn't about the table column having a precision. C#'s `decimal` has no precision so `14.123456` is a perfectly valid value. This won't match with the stored value `14.1234`. If the value gets rounded it will become `14.1235`, not `14.1234`

Comment: I'm aware, but unfortunately we don't have a better value that we could include instead. But given the high precision this should never be an issue with the actual data we receive.

Comment: That's not the point. `System.Decimal` has no precision. You may have specified the *table column's scale* but the property `UnitPriceIncl` has no precision and can *easily* cause problems. That's why you get this warning.

Comment: And once again, using `price` in a primary key is extremely unusual and almost certainly a sign of design issues. Invoices have lines. The lines have products and prices, they aren't identified by those products and prices. You already have invoice lines with different prices for the same product. What if some items are delivered in parts, so different quantities of the same product and price are delivered on different dates? Or have rebates? Different shipping fees?

Comment: I understand that you suggest a redesign. Unfortunately that is not an option at the since we literally don't have more fields on the position. Given the code is live for 6 Months + without issues, the risk in our specific situation is very low and we don't need more informationthe pressure to introduce more is very low. So the question is, if there is a way to tell EF Core for this particular case that it is fine. I know that I can supress the error globally, but I would like to keep the warning on for other cases.

Comment: Then add an `ID` that's automatically generated, eg an IDENTITY in SQL Server. That's what all tutorials show by the way